# How to auto ban an IP when he access some ports?

Tags: networking, security, iptables, netstat

I have a vps, which host some service only I used. 
Today, I found someone scaning my vps by

```
netstat -ntu | awk '{print $5}' |sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

And found some result(I have removed my ip from below)

```
1 xxxxxxxxxxx:59564
1 xxxxxxxxxxx:59569
1 xxxxxxxxxxx:59570
1 xxxxxxxxxxx:59576
1 120.236.148.199:2226
1 127.0.0.1:41108
1 127.0.0.1:41148
1 127.0.0.1:41156
1 127.0.0.1:41158
1 127.0.0.1:41178
1 127.0.0.1:41180
1 183.61.236.54:3128
1 213.13.37.231:3128
1 218.244.149.184:8888
1 46.164.141.173:8080
1 58.96.172.205:8888
1 Address
1 servers)
2 ::1:9988
2 219.156.157.186:80
10 127.0.0.1:3306
11 127.0.0.1:3999
```

I have some webservice only for myself, I want to ban all ip once they access other ports, but there are some problems.

1. I setup a socks5 proxy on 8699, but it seems open some other port to serve my connection:

   ```
   tcp6       0      0 default.hostname:8699   my_vps_ip_here.bro:59570 ESTABLISHED
   tcp6       0      0 default.hostname:8699   my_vps_ip_here.bro:59576 ESTABLISHED
   tcp6       0      0 default.hostname:8699   my_vps_ip_here.bro:59564 ESTABLISHED
   tcp6       0      0 default.hostname:8699   my_vps_ip_here.bro:59569 ESTABLISHED
   ```

   `netstat -ntu | awk '{print $5}' |sort | uniq -c | sort -n` doesn't shows I am connecting `8699`, only shows `59570, 59576, 59564, 59569`. What is the correct rule for this case ?
2. What is the recommended way to automatically ban IP? I only come up with: keep check the result of `netstat -ntu | awk '{print $5}' |sort | uniq -c | sort -n` every second, and add bad ip to iptables.
3. I know iptables and ufw can ban ip,  ufw looks more like a manager, but is there any better choice ?

Comment: You are mistaken, you still connect via 8699 you just get forked to another port because if it wouldn't do that there could always be only 1 user connecting to a port.

Answer (score 1):

**

> What is the recommended way to automatically ban IP?

**

iptables and ufw can do better with a little automation.
fail2ban does that and I would recommend that as a good choice.
Do preliminary checks,

- check for established connections
  sudo lsof -i -n | egrep '<sshd>' | grep ESTABLISHED
  sudo lsof -i -n | egrep '<ssh>' | grep ESTABLISHED
- check for weird users & sudo-ers

  ```
  getent group sudo | cut -d: -f4
  grep -Po '^sudo.+:\K.*$' /etc/group
  ```

**Persistent Bans**

With a little tweak, you can ban repeated attempts and restore the ban in effect.

install fail2ban,

```
apt install fail2ban
```

now edit the multiport.conf file in fail2ban vim or nano,

```
nano /etc/fail2ban/action.d/iptables-multiport.conf
```

append these lines to 'actionstart' (from 4th line i guess )

```
cat /etc/fail2ban/persistent.bans | awk '/^fail2ban-<name>/ {print $2}' \
          | while read IP; do iptables -I fail2ban-<name> 1 -s $IP -j <blocktype>; done
```

such that it looks something like this

```
[Definition]

# Option:  actionstart
# Notes.:  command executed once at the start of Fail2Ban.
# Values:  CMD
#
actionstart = <iptables> -N f2b-<name>
              <iptables> -A f2b-<name> -j <returntype>
              <iptables> -I <chain> -p <protocol> -m multiport --dports <port> -j f2b-<name>
        cat /etc/fail2ban/persistent.bans | awk '/^fail2ban-<name>/ {print $2}' \
          | while read IP; do iptables -I fail2ban-<name> 1 -s $IP -j <blocktype>; done
```

append this line to 'actionban' right after the line `actionban = ...` for a persistent ban on the ips

```
echo "fail2ban-<name> <ip>" >> /etc/fail2ban/persistent.bans
```

now restart fail2ban,

```
sudo service fail2ban restart
```

and give some 'ban'

```
   sudo fail2ban-client set sshd banip  112.0.0.0/8  
   sudo fail2ban-client set sshd banip  222.186.0.0/16
```

now check for effective persistent bans,

```
tail /var/log/fail2ban.log
```

you should see something like,

```
NOTICE  [sshd] Restore Ban 112.0.0.0/8
```

this way repeated attacks can be avoided and now you can use iptables to allow just for your ip

PS: as fail2ban works on banning persistently the attackers, you can just relax and make sure no ESTABLISHED connections to the services using,

```
sudo lsof -i -n | egrep '\<ssh\>'   
sudo lsof -i -n | egrep '\<sshd\>'
```

(note that you need specific 'jail' for specific service ) and see the persistent bans

```
cat /etc/fail2ban/persistent.bans
```

Output:

```
fail2ban-sshd 112.0.0.0/8
fail2ban-sshd 218.92.0.0/16
fail2ban-sshd 218.92.0.138
```

**Explanation**

1. actionstart:  we can add some action commands that will execute only during fail2ban start. so, we added `/etc/fail2ban/persistent.bans` during start
2. actionban: whenever a ban is imposed on an ip, the ip is added to persistent.bans file which will be in effect during the fail2ban run. You can relaxed-edit this file later if you feel an ip is not involved in malicious attacks.
3. you can manually ban ip's in question using

   ```
   sudo fail2ban-client set sshd banip  112.0.0.0/8  
   sudo fail2ban-client set sshd banip  222.186.0.0/16
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**psad** checks for portscans and can react accordingly, check this [link](https://www.unixmen.com/how-to-block-port-scan-attacks-with-psad-on-ubuntu-debian/) for a short description on how to configure it. I just googled it, there are numerous other tutorials as well. It is available in the ubuntu repositories, see [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/psad.8.html).

Also **Fail2ban** could be something for you, see their [wiki](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8#Introduction) for more info.
It essentially checks log-files for you and can block IP-addresses automatically. It is available in the ubuntu repositories, see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fail2ban).

Comment: These tools are great to use. May you briefly describe how to install/use these tools rather than including external links?